# Redirect root domain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Here is our current .htaccess file with the rules we need to keep but also we need to add a new rule that redirects from the root domain to a subfolder URL
`example.com -> example.com/fl/en.html`..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.nz$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/home.html|/info.html|/flash|/external)
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/fl/en.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything particularly special required, providing you put the directive in the correct place. To redirect the document root (for `example.com`) to `/fl/en.html` in `.htaccess` can be done like so:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /fl/en.html [R,L]
```

This just needs to go *after* the directive that rewrites everything for the host `domain.co.nz` and *before* your front-controller. (You could potentially combine this with your existing directive that redirects `/home.html`, `/info.html`, etc.)

Your existing rules could be further optimised. Instead of checking the requested URL-path in a `RewriteCond` directive and allowing *everything* through in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, it is more efficient to do what you can in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* first (since this is what is processed first).

Also, since you are using WordPress, any custom directives you add to `.htaccess` should be outside of the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. WordPress itself maintains this section, so any manual customisations you make could be overwritten during an update.

Also, there is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. (The *last* instance of this directive wins and controls the entire file.)

So, bringing all this together, we have something like:

```
# Rewrite all requests for domain.co.nz to subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.nz$
RewriteRule !^subfolder /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Redirect document root to /fl/en.html
RewriteRule ^$ /fl/en.html [R,L]    

# Redirect specific paths to /fl/en.html
RewriteRule ^(/home.html|/info.html|/flash|/external) /fl/en.html [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    
</IfModule>    
# END WordPress
```

Note that the above directive (with a single `R`) is a temporary (302) redirect. Change this to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent, but only once you have tested that it's working OK (to avoid caching issues).

As always, make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing.